# Access Control Allow Origin header Error Only in Chrome,Safari but not Opera

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

I have enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin on my apache webserver. I am able to load all requests on the first load. However, subsequent loading/refreshing of the pages would leave half of the requests failed, leaving an error of,

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://***. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

In Chrome Developer Tool, under the Network tab, enabling "Disable Cache" removes this error.

I am using AngularJS $http to call my request, I have changed the cache option to true/false but this abnormality persist. For your information, I am also using an angular-cache module, https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache, I have tried enabling/disabling this too, but to no avail.

Here is a copy of the request header:

```
GET ***Valid_Url_With_Parameters** HTTP/1.1
Host: ********
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

I have a 2 different types response header with different HTTP status codes for the failed requests.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 564121
Content-Type: application/json
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Vary: Accept
Last-Modified: Fri, 16 Sep 2016 12:41:41 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Fri, 16 Sep 2016 12:43:44 GMT


HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Type: application/json
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Vary: Accept
Last-Modified: Fri, 16 Sep 2016 13:39:05 GMT
Content-Range: bytes 29200-29200/785592
Content-Length: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Fri, 16 Sep 2016 14:20:48 GMT
```

It seems something to do with caching. The first time the page loads, all of the request have the correct access control header. Subsequent refresh/reload removes this header. How can I continue using caching and keep the access control header?

Edit:

Just to add on, I tried using Safari, the same abnormality appeared. It load on the first try but subsequent loading will throw a no access control allow origin error. However, this time, the response header in Safari shows blank.

Edit 2:

Abnormality appears in Firefox as well but not in Opera Beta version    40.0.2308.52. I am beginning to wonder if this is the cause of the browser. Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present too.

Response Header in Opera

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 17 Sep 2016 06:56:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Vary: Accept
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Edit 3:
I would like to add that the requests that I'm pulling is a large amount of data. I am pulling the last 7 days history of data, there are about 20 JSON files, each ranging from 500KB to 1000KB. I noticed that when I change the query parameter to pull in a small history of data, this error does not happen.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes it does depend on browser to browser, though have you tried adding Content Security Meta Tag in your web app

Comment: @PrateekRathore No I have not. Can you kindly elaborate more on that or how I can add it?

Comment: add this in <head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
      content="default-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'">
well you can add more and make it more fruitful as in by implementing true meaning of Content Security Policy

Comment: @PrateekRathore I have added that in the header but unfortunately the cross origin error persist. I have also tried adding the URL of the API onto default-src and the error still persist.

Comment: You also have to put Allow Access Origin Header in your server .htaccess file. have you done that?

Comment: @PrateekRathore Yes I have, I use the guide from http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123586/discussion-between-prateek-rathore-and-park-taecyeon).

Answer (score 0):

One work around I've found is to dynamically generate a javascript file on the server as resource included into your page. This doesn't require AJAX the which gets blocked by CORS and can be cached.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible as I have very little access to the server API. It's controlled by a third party.

Answer (score 0):

We had this same problem in Chrome when returning a specific value in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header. We were able to solve it by also including `Vary: Origin` in the response headers.

It appears Chrome considers response headers, including 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', as part of the cached response. So if it requests the same file from a different origin, that header from the cache will not match. But if you include `Vary: Origin` it lets Chrome know the response (just this one header in our case) will be different based on the Origin of the request.

This [page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin#cors_and_caching) explains it:

> If the server sends a response with an Access-Control-Allow-Origin
> value that is an explicit origin (rather than the "*" wildcard), then
> the response should also include a Vary response header with the value
> Origin — to indicate to browsers that server responses can differ
> based on the value of the Origin request header.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to add chrome extension in your browser

> Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *